# Run Javascript snow onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to run Dynamic Drive's JS Snow only (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/snow.htm) once the user has clicked the button.

I have tried enclosing all the code in a function and running the function onclick but it just puts me on a white page with the snow frozen.

How would I do this?

Comment: Tis the season already?

Comment: @m90 You have to be ready when it comes.

Comment: I actually replaced the snow with bananas for a joke website.

Answer (score 1):

1) Move this part into separate function:

```
function startStuff() {
    if (ie4up||ns6up){
        snowIE_NS6();
    if (hidesnowtime>0)
        setTimeout("hidesnow()", hidesnowtime*1000)
    }
}
```

2) Assign onclick event like `<a href="#" onclick="startStuff()">start</a>`

Comment: Nope, still not doing it.
I'm getting a snow flake in the top right before you click the button and after it the whole page just goes blank with frozen snow flakes again.

Comment: Actually, it works now, it was just me putting your code in wrong :P
Thanks!